# Line Spacing on Itext or Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, java, itext

Can I change paragraph line space on existing PDF? Not a new PDF.
Please tell me how to change. Every ways. Thanks.

Comment: I would to change with manual ways. Like java or javascript.

Comment: Very often a PDF is converted from an editable file format like HTML or Microsoft Word. Change the paragraph line space in the original document and convert again. If you don't have an original editable file format, see Joris' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether your PDF document is tagged or not, and how much effort you are willing to invest in machine learning and AI, the answer varies from "maybe" to "not a million years"

Let me explain.

A PDF document is mostly a collection of instructions that tell a viewer how to render the document. It (usually) does not contain any logical structure.
So even if you (the human end user) can clearly see a paragraph, that does not mean the computer is capable of telling which parts of the document make up a paragraph or not.

If your document is tagged (meaning it has this logical structure):

- changing the line-height might require you to perform layout again
- images may need to be placed at slightly different locations
- pages may overflow
- tables may no longer fit
- etc

You would need to provide code to be able to handle all of these cases.
And this is even the `happy flow`.

If your document is untagged, the task becomes much more difficult.
Getting a computer to recognize structure in raw PDF content is hard. It's the task of ongoing research in many PDF companies.
And you'll find a lot of thesis papers written on this very subject. Most people tend to focus on extracting a single kind of information (like tables, or lists, or text), rather than all information.

In short, the answer is *probably not*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer makes me convinced.